# Finding the index of a number using a 'while' function in a randomly generated range

Tags: python, while-loop, jupyter-notebook

I was given this homework question:

1. Start with two lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(10_000) #this generates 10,000 random numbers from a uniform distribution over [0,1)
```

Now, write a loop to find the index of the first value in x that is greater than 0.999. Stop the loop when you find it.

2. Do the same exercise as 1, but use a while loop instead.

For number 1 I wrote this and it worked:

```
for i, num in enumerate(x):
    if num > 0.999:
        print(i)
        break
```

For number 2 I have not been able to figure it out.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: A `for` loop is just a special case of the more general `while` loop.  You just need to define your own counter variable, and increment it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a while loop, just create a variable which you increment over each iteration to find the index of the x variable once the while loop's condition is met.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(10_000)

#For loop
for i, num in enumerate(x):
    if num > 0.999:
        print(i)
        break

#While loop
i = 0
while x[i] < 0.999:
    i += 1
print(i)
```